# map through an object and fill another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map through the data.scales array of objects and display the values in the obj createvalues array as shown in the output. I cannot quite figure this out.
I have to make sure I do not delete the values existing in the createValues array

```
const obj = {
projecd: 0,
grd: 0,
crea: [
  {
    field: 1,
    value: "cool"
  },
  {
    field: 11,
    value: "cl"
  },
  {
    field: 11,
    value: "cool"
  }
]
};

const data = {
scs:[
  {
    SleId:15,
    Value:"LOW"
  },
   {
    eId:105,
    Value:"LOW"
  }  
] 
};
const result = Object.entries(data.ses).map(([key, value]) => ({
field: data.sces.value,
value: data.scas.value
}));

console.log(result)
obj.createues=
```

The output expected is this one :

```
const output = {
projecd: 0,
gri: 0,
createues: [
   {
    field: 1111,
    value: "cool"
  },
  {
    field: 141,
    value: "cl"
  },
  {
    field: 11,
    value: "cool"
  }
  {
    field: 15,
    value: "LOW"
  },
  {
  field: 165,
  value: "LOW"
}
]
};
```

Comment: why are there 2 in scales array and expected array only 1?

Comment: Do you need to mutate the original obj or must it be a new object?

Comment: the best would be to add the value to the actual object

Comment: any way I can use object.entries ?

Comment: `Object.entries()` is used on Objects. Since scales  is an array, you can use `Array.entries()`.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, continuing from your solution you can do

**Solution 1**

```
const results = Object.entries(data.scales).map(([key, value]) => {
    return ({
        field: value.ScaleId,
        value: value.Value
   })
});
obj.createValues = [...obj.createValues, ...results]; // Use spread operator to combine two arrays
```

**Solution 2**

You can also make use of [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of to loop directly through scales

This method allows you to loop through the array elements. You can find the value in the `createValues` array of objects and if does not exists you can then push the new object into `obj.createValues`.

I have only checked for value, you can add condition for field ID if needed in `find` method.

```
data.scales.map(sc => {
    if(obj.createValues.find(v => v.value !== sc.Value)) {
        obj.createValues.push({field: sc.ScaleId, value: sc.Value})
    }
})
```

Solution Snippet:

```js
const obj = {
  projectId: 0,
  gridId: 0,
  createValues: [
    {
      field: 1111,
      value: "cool"
    },
    {
      field: 13341,
      value: "cl"
    },
    {
      field: 1111,
      value: "cool"
    }
  ]
};

const data = {
  scales:[
    {
      ScaleId:109165,
      Value:"LOW"
    },
     {
      ScaleId:109165,
      Value:"LOW"
    }  
  ] 
};

data.scales.map(sc => {
    if(obj.createValues.find(v => v.value !== sc.Value)) {
        obj.createValues.push({field: sc.ScaleId, value: sc.Value})
    }
})
console.log(obj)
```